# Take the first values from a list of ReplaySubjects, do something specific and then continue streaming the remaining values

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs, observable

I have a use case that I wasn't able to find specifically on SO and my lack of understanding of rxjs and Observables in general has made me try a few of things that don't work.

My use case is basically this, I have a list of ReplaySubject<1> that continually emit updates to a certain fields. I'm successfully able to emit these values to a child component in real time and that works for me. But the parent component that renders the child does not get the updated state. The state always get updated correctly in console but only after the parent component renders which is too late (so we get Nans and 0 there instead) and I'm trying to figure out how to cleanly explain my requirement. To try and be more concise, I need :-

The first value each from a list of ReplaySubjects that I know will be continually emitting, and I need my code to wait or be aware of when they return before returning something to the component that renders it. The updates always happen after the first data is returned to the component that renders it.

What works for continuously streaming to child :-

```
listOfReplaySubjects.forEach((sub, idx)) => {
  sub.subscribe(latestVal => {
    // Do some transformation using idx
    childEmitter.emit(transformedVal)
  }
}
```

This works because the child component is rendered only after a user click on the parent component, meaning there has been enough time for all of these to emit at least 1 value to populate the child table. My issue now is that I need the sum of all these values in the parent component itself, and I only need the first point in time value. (Else I would have to keep subtracting the previous value from the sum to keep the total correct, which is also fine) In either of these cases, I am unable to get my parent component to wait for at least one value to be emitted, and I am unable to figure it out.

Things I have tried :-

1. forkJoin or combineLatest using a list of ReplaySubjects with a return statement inside the function

```
let observables = []
listOfReplaySubjects.forEach((sub, idx)) => {
  observables.push(sub)
  //Have also tried sub.pipe(first())
  }
}

forkJoin(..observables).subscribe( res => { // Do my one time  logic here});
```

2. Random combinations of async and awaits that I don't fully understand
3. Setting a timeout after the subscription (it is either too less time or too long a time before the parent component gets rendered)

Comment: Can you maybe provide a stackblitz with some sample code to showcase your problem?

Comment: @Mikelgo: Will need some time as i will have to do it in my own time, but I will definitely try to make a reproducable sample and get back to you